# how to remove syntax error while using range(len(data)) in an html page in django?

Tags: html, django

I am sending my data to Html page in tuple format and want to display using `range(len(data))` in Html page in Django but it is showing this error

`" Could not parse the remainder: '(len(data))' from 'range(len(data))' "`

please help.

Comment: why do you need to use range within `data` length if you can simple iterate over data itself `{% for item in data %} {{ item.0 }} {{ item.1 }} {% endif %}

Comment: Your question is not clear. Show us some code

Answer (score 2):

You cannot directly do that. if you wanted to print data one by one you can directly do this

> At HTML side

```
{% for item in data %}

     <p> {{ item }} </p>

{% endfor %}
```

> It will print information which inside in **data** at one by one.

If you want to print a length of data then you can do `{{ data|length }}` to print **length** of **data**.

Answer (score 0):

It's not especially clear what you are wanting to acieve...

If you are wanting to just display the range of the length then perhaps you need to do the evalutation of the data before it gets sent to the template. If you are using class based views, then you can use the `get_context_data()` method. E.g.

views.py:

```
class MyView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'my_template.html'
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        data = Data.objects.get(id=1)
        return {'data': range(len(data))}
```